# system.log is flooded with mDNSResponder messages: "queryrecord_result_callback:..."

Tags: macos, logs, dns

My Mac is constantly writing the same following error message to `system.log`:

```
...
Feb 18 15:24:21 MBA mDNSResponder[51]: queryrecord_result_callback: mDNS_Lock: Locking failure! mDNS_busy (1) != mDNS_reentrancy (0)
Feb 18 15:24:21 MBA mDNSResponder[51]: queryrecord_result_callback: mDNS_Unlock: Locking failure! mDNS_busy (1) != mDNS_reentrancy (0)
Feb 18 15:24:21 MBA mDNSResponder[51]: queryrecord_result_callback: mDNS_Lock: Locking failure! mDNS_busy (1) != mDNS_reentrancy (0)
Feb 18 15:24:21 MBA mDNSResponder[51]: queryrecord_result_callback: mDNS_Unlock: Locking failure! mDNS_busy (1) != mDNS_reentrancy (0)
Feb 18 15:24:21 MBA mDNSResponder[51]: queryrecord_result_callback: mDNS_Lock: Locking failure! mDNS_busy (1) != mDNS_reentrancy (0)
Feb 18 15:24:21 MBA mDNSResponder[51]: queryrecord_result_callback: mDNS_Unlock: Locking failure! mDNS_busy (1) != mDNS_reentrancy (0)
...
```

Throughout the day this accumulates to **thousands** of messages which forced me to simply press the "Ignore Sender" button to spot other entries.

#### How can I troubleshoot this behavior?

Comment: The tool to use is `dns-sd` but I don't have much to offer on the process of using it. I've gotten awesome answers using dns-sd from [DrFrogSplat](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1587/drfrogsplat) but most google hits I see are old RFP and manual page entries.

Comment: Also, I'd start by isolating my Mac from a network to ensure you are not just seeing a very chatty network. I'd place a second router between my Mac and the internet so I'm on an isolated NAT protected route to the world. (or a private VLAN if you have one) and reboot with networking disabled. Then you can watch as zeroconf runs in a garden before subjecting your Mac to all the devices on your network.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the suggestion but I don't have access to a second router to test this. Maybe I could just clear all known networks and then reboot with networking disabled? How should I monitor "zeroconf"?